# Regular expression to convert raw text into columns of data

Tags: r, regex

I have a raw text output from a program that I want to convert into a `DataFrame`. The text file is not formatted and is as shown below.

```
 10037    149439Special Event       11538.00       13542.59   2004.59
 10070     10071Weekday        8234.00        9244.87   1010.87
 10216     13463Weekend        145.00              0   -145.00
```

I am able to read the data into `R` using `readLines()` in the base package. How can I convert this into data that looks like this (column names can be anything).

```
 A        B         C              D              E          F
 10037    149439    Special Event  11538.00       13542.59   2004.59
 10070     10071    Weekday        8234.00         9244.87   1010.87
 10216     13463    Weekend        145.00                0   -145.00
```

What regular expression should I use to achieve this? I know that this is ideal for applying a combination of `regexec()` and `regmatches()`. But I am unable to come up with an expression that splits the line into the desired components.

Comment: if your text file is not too big you could do this in excel using Data -Text to Columns option

Comment: @user2510479 The OP mentions in the tags the use of the `R` programming language, which is the antithesis of Excel.

Comment: People still use Excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
raw <- readLines("filename.txt")
data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(raw, " {2,}|(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE)))

#       X1     X2            X3       X4       X5      X6
# 1  10037 149439 Special Event 11538.00 13542.59 2004.59
# 2  10070  10071       Weekday  8234.00  9244.87 1010.87
# 3  10216  13463       Weekend   145.00        0 -145.00
```

The regular expression `" {2,}|(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Z])"` consists of two parts, combined with `"|"` (logical *or*).

1. `" {2,}"` means at least two spaces. This will split between the different columns only, since the text in the third column has a single space.
2. `"(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Z])"` denotes the positions that are preceded by a digit and followed by an uppercase letter. This is used to split between the second and the third column.

Comment: Can you please explain the expression you have constructed?

Comment: @RazorXsr See my explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I created `"txt.txt"` from your data.  Then we work some with a regular expression.

```
> read <- readLines("txt.txt")
> S <- strsplit(read, "[A-Za-z]|\\s")
> W <- do.call(rbind, lapply(S, function(x) x[nzchar(x)]))
> D <- data.frame(W[,1:2], col, W[,3:5])
> names(D) <- LETTERS[seq(D)]
> D
##       A      B            C        D        E       F
## 1 10037 149439 SpecialEvent 11538.00 13542.59 2004.59
## 2 10070  10071      Weekday  8234.00  9244.87 1010.87
## 3 10216  13463      Weekend   145.00        0 -145.00
```

Toss it all into some curly brackets and you've got yourself a function to parse your files.

**PS**: If the space between "Special" and "Event" is important, please comment and I'll revise.

Comment: Bravo! This is some pretty neat stuff which is going to be extremely useful. It will be interesting to see how the space can be maintained only within the character string.

Answer (score 0):

[Something like this](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GJ_PMNJZ6vTTfoRx) at least works on your example but I don't know all your corner cases...

```
([0-9]+) +([0-9]+)(.+) ([0-9.-]+) +([0-9.-]+) +([0-9.-]+)
```

The captured groups from 1 to 6 are resp. your columns from A to F.

Comment: This regex will put all but one of the spaces following the third column into the match for the third column.